# Load SSIS package after specific event

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, data-warehouse

My SSIS package gets data from Oracle materialized view (I load this data to my SQL Server warehouse). It's materialized in different time, so I want to addict start of my SSIS package on finished materialization.

At first I thought to put this package in loop and check every some amount of time if Oracle materialized view is full.

Anyone know better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there're 3 system views that you can check

- DBA_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES
- USER_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES
- ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES

[see the oracle docs link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1104.htm#REFRN20138)

you can setup oracle job and make some like this check in the job:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES 
where last_refresh between '29-OCT-10' AND '31-OCT-10' and NAME = 'MY_MVIEW';
```

Comment: To load this data we use SQL Server Job, but I don't have access to change it. It is any possible to do it without permission?

Comment: actually you can put the check into your SSIS and if the mview was updated - reload your data into MSSQL, if not - set pause until next try

Comment: You mean specific SSIS block to do it?

Comment: yeap. you have access to the view, so you should be able get value from last_refresh column via USER_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES or ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES.